# only 3 users shoud be inserted into the database within a timespan of 5 months

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Reposting the question after making some changes which i deleted earlier.
I tried hard but I could not figure out how to achieve it.

I have a table fw_invitations

```
ID  OFFICEID  Consultationdate
------------------------------
1     1       16-06-2013
2     1       16-06-2013
3     1       16-06-2013
4     1       17-08-2014
5     1       17-08-2014
```

`$consultationdate` contains the date entered by the user.

```
$invcount="Select count(*) as   noofinv,
           Datediff('$consultationdate',max(consultationdate)) as datediffinv 
           from fw_invitations where OFFICEID = 1";

$db->setQuery($invcount);
$invcounts=$db->loadAssoclist();
$noofinv=$invcounts[0]['noofinv'];
$datediffinv=abs($invcounts[0]['datediffinv']);

if($noofinv >3 && $datediffinv <150)
{
  $error_message="Het maximale ";
}
```

I am also trying this but the below query always resulting in 0

```
    $invcount="Select count(*) as noofinv from fw_invitations
    where consultationdate between 
    DATE_SUB($consultationdate,INTERVAL 150 DAY) and
    DATE_ADD($consultationdate,INTERVAL 150 DAY) from fw_invitations where OFFICEID = 1";
```

what I want to do is that not more than 3 user should be inserted into the table if the datediff is more than 150(5 months).

My above query was working perfectly unless I entered the date with a long interval. Since I am using `max(consultationdate)` so max date for the above table will be 17-08-2014, it will not validate the case in which a user again enters the date 16-06-2013.

*In short, what I want to do is in any case only 3 users shoud be inserted into the database within a timespan of 5 months.*

Comment: Why did you delete your first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019067/only-3-users-should-be-inserted-into-the-database-within-a-timespan-on-5-months#20019067 and repost this one??

Comment: too much caps and too many negative votes because of which i started to think that i asked an idiotic question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i missed the single quotes in the $consultationdate thats ahy it was resulting 0 everytime,after correcting that its working like a charm .

```
 $invcount="Select count(*) as noofinv from fw_invitations
        where consultationdate between 
        DATE_SUB('$consultationdate',INTERVAL 150 DAY) and
        DATE_ADD('$consultationdate',INTERVAL 150 DAY) from fw_invitations where OFFICEID = 1";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this like so (pseudocode!):

```
function isAllowed($entry) {
    $before = SELECT all entries from past 5 months;
    $after = SELECT all entries from next 5 months;

    if(count($before) >= 3 || count($after) >= 3) {
        return false;
    }
    if(count($before) == 0 || count($after) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    $all = array_merge($before, array($entry), $after);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($before); $i++) {
        if(isset($all[$i + 2])) {
            $first = $all[$i];
            $last = $all[$i + 2];
            if($last->date < $first->date + 5 months) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i will do +1 for your idea but can u suggest how to implement that in mysql also i want to write an optimize code.

Comment: I think this is a little complex for pure mysql. Why do you want to implement it in mysql? You would still need the result in PHP and there you decide wether to insert the new entry or to print an error message.