# Date 22 months increments during record insertion in php mysql in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 

$current_date=date("Y-m-d"); 

$vacation=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `employee` 
                       WHERE `employe_no`='$employe_no'");

$showvacation=mysql_fetch_array($vacation);
$date=$showvacation['joinng_date'];
$mod_date = strtotime($date."+ 22 months");
$due_date=date("Y-m-d",$mod_date); 
?>
```

is it possible on when inserting a new record date automatically 22 month are adding?
basically I working a HR web application and every 22 month vacation due start .

Comment: How is the date stored? What loop are you talking about? What have you tried so far? It's hard to answer this question accurately without more details.

Comment: every affter 22 month vacation start 2 month...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i understood from your question you want something like:

```
$customDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+22 months", strtotime($customDate)));
```

or maybe you want something like this :

[only 3 users shoud be inserted into the database within a timespan of 5 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019163/only-3-users-shoud-be-inserted-into-the-database-within-a-timespan-of-5-months)

Comment: @user3065784 check my update and if possible update your question with proper code.

Comment: who on earth approved that clearly invalid edit? OP asks "i have a table with the name of vacation. and other table employes and after joinng date(in employe table) +22 months =due date how to do it?"

Comment: @OGHaza what you are implying here,please elaborate.

Comment: @OGHaza aah now i see,anyways forget it as that is not main concern here :)